# How do I set up and use classes, libraries, packages in Java?

Tags: java, class

I'm new enough to the idea of using external class libraries and APIs not native to Java that I don't even know if I'm asking the right questions with the right terminology. So let me explain what I'm doing.

I need to read and write to an Excel file. I found [this page](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html) that has a Java-Excel API. I want to get that API installed and available for my local instance of Java (`C:\java\`) so I can just import these classes when i create a new program (e.g., `import jxl.CellView`). I have a zip file from [sourceforge](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), but after that, I'm just lost.

The instructions reference setting it up in Eclipse; I'm not a fan of Eclipse as an IDE...so I want to know how to do it "manually". I think this will help me better understand why it works the way it does for the future.

So, my next instruction is...
"To use this library in your Java program add the lib jxl.jar to your classpath in your project. See Changing classpath in Eclipse." Do I just unzip the zip file to `C:\java`? Is that what they mean by my class path? What are the steps I need to follow from here to ensure I can import the appropriate classes as needed?

Further, do these classes get bundled with applets? When I compile a java program, will the recipient of that file be able to run it even if they don't have this particular package installed on the machine on which they're running it?

Can someone give me some perspective on this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to put all my third party libraries in c:\java\lib.  That way I can keep them separate from the JREs and JDKs I have in c:\java.  This is not strictly necessary, but it's nice to be tidy.  Here are some instructions specific to using the library you're interested in.

Extract `jexcelapi_2_6_12.zip` to `c:\java\lib\`.

This should mean the following file now exists: `C:\java\lib\jexcelapi\jxl.jar`.

Let's put your code in `c:\java\work` for now, to keep it separate.  Create the file `c:\java\work\MyClass.java` using a text editor:

```
import jxl.CellView;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("I can access " + CellView.class);
    }
}
```

Open a command prompt and change directory to c:\java\work.

`cd /d c:\java\work`

Now compile the class:

`javac -classpath ..\lib\jexcelapi\jxl.jar MyClass.java`

If you get no errors, the directory should now contain a new file `MyClass.class`, which is your compiled program.

If you see the error:
*'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.* then you could specify the full path to javac.exe.  The following example assumes you have a JDK located in c:\java\jdk1.6.0_37, which may or may not be true on your system:

`c:\java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javac -classpath ..\lib\jexcelapi\jxl.jar MyClass.java`

Run your compiled program:

`C:\java\work>java -classpath ..\lib\jexcelapi\jxl.jar;. MyClass`

Output:
*I can access class jxl.CellView*

Notice the semicolon and dot at the end of the `java` classpath.  This adds the current directory to the classpath so that java can find MyClass.class.  That was not necessary with `javac`.

Unlike `PATH`, which should contain only directories, java's `CLASSPATH` (or `-classpath`) can contain both files and directories.  When a file appears in the classpath it should be a JAR.  Since JARs are just zip files, you sometimes also see ZIP files in classpaths.  This is non-standard, but it works.  Java will treat the .zip file as a .jar.  If you needed to add some second library to your program, separate the files with a semicolon (Windows) or colon (*nix).

`javac -classpath ..\lib\jexcelapi\jxl.jar;..\lib\lib-2.0\lib-2.0.jar MyClass.java`

Sometimes libraries consist of more than one jar file.  In this case, you will need to add every JAR file that is a part of the library to the classpath.  Again, separate them with semicolons.  If this seems tedious, you'll start to see why people like to use IDEs or Ant to work with Java rather than command line commands.

There are many things still to learn like using packages, using the environment variable CLASSPATH to set the classpath instead of using the `-classpath` command line argument, adding your JDK bin directory to your PATH, adding more than one entry to the classpath, creating shell scripts to make rebuilding and rerunning your program easier, using IDEs for development, and Maven/Ant for building, making your own JARs, ... the list of things to learn goes on and on.  This post is not meant to indicate best practices, but rather to get you up and running quickly.  Follow the Oracle documentation and other best practices posted on the Internet to keep improving your Java development environment.

*Further, do these classes get bundled with applets?*
If your program is eventually going to be an applet, then yes, you will need to distribute jxl.jar with your program -- people are not going to have it on their computer, nor are they going to want to download it on their own. I am not going to describe how to make Applets here.  There are lots of resources on the web.  Google for it and come back with more specific questions about problems you run into.

*When I compile a java program, will the recipient of that file be able to run it even if they don't have this particular package installed on the machine on which they're running it?*
The jxl library does not get compiled into your program.  You will need to deliver the jxl library to your users somehow, along with your program.  You should probably bundle your program up into a JAR, since most non-trivial programs consist of more than one Java class, and that means your program will consist of multiple .class files. There are a number of ways to approach this problem.  Spend some time reading resources on how to create applets and then come back to stackoverflow with more specific questions.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks loads. This gets me started enough to learn the right questions to ask once I roll up my sleeves and start working with the API.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against dropping all your libraries into a single directory; unless you explicitly name them by version (as generally happens when you use a real versioning system like Maven) you're asking for trouble as soon as you have more than one version. Also, Java classpaths can contain wildcards now, although particularly if you're throwing random versions into directories, you'll be at the mercy of the classloader. Better to keep a project-specific library directory.

Comment: @DaveNewton 95% of the libraries I use, when extracted normally, contain a version number in the directory they create. This is enough to keep things organized in c:\java\lib. Unfortunately "jexcelapi" doesn't do this. I personally would rename the "jexcel" directory to "jexcel-2.6.12" before moving forward. And/or use a project-specific lib directory ala maven.  But let's be practical -- this guy wasn't even able to run basic `java` + `javac` successfully. There's a limit to how much "best practice" I'm going to confuse him with while just trying to get him up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the command line.

Type in:

```
echo %CLASSPATH%
```

It should return a list of directories. You can put the library you want to import into any of them.

Read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: `echo %CLASSPATH%` returns `.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip` which makes no sense to me--a path is a zip file? Unless paths have changed since I was elbows deep on DOS 3.3 and edlin (shudder), I don't get how that works. What am I missing?

Comment: In that case use the instructions in the tutorial to add a directory to the classpath and put it in that directory

Comment: so the zip file as my path basically indicates that an invalid path has been set? Just trying to understand why it didn't return an undefined variable error, and why things WORK if my classpath is a zip file...

Comment: I don't think having a zip file is invalid. I think it just puts all the classes in that zip on the classpath. What you want is to add a directory with your library to the zip in addition to the zip file.

Comment: copy that. thanks for the info! i've never seen that before.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The classpath is a list of directories and `.jar` files, from which the the Java virtual machine loads classes it needs. Some directories and jars are in there by default (basically the libraries that come with the Java installation), others have to be specified by the user.

One way to specify additional places it the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. If there is more than one entry separate it by the platform's path separator (semicolon on Windows, colon for most other systems).

The other way is the `-classpath` option when you start the compiler or the java virtual machine.

In your case, put the `jxl.jar` file somewhere (say `/some/path/jxl.jar`) and then invoke the compiler as (assuming, MyClass is in the default package and stored in the current directory)

```
javac -classpath /some/path/jxl.jar:. MyClass.java
```

and to run it use

```
java -classpath /some/path/jxl.jar:. MyClass
```

Comment: (With the caveat you may need to explicitly include the current directory, IIRC this depends on the Java version.)

Answer (score 0):

in the zip file you have jxl.jar, you have to include this jxl.jar in your proyect like external library.
For example in netbeans:

http://jsumon.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/adding-external-jar-or-library-to-netbeans-java-project/

and eclipse:

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29